# Ресурс, видео, книги по принципам реализации сайтов

Tags: php, книги

Добрый вечер. У меня такая проблема... Я изучал php последние полгода. Учил много, знаю много, в том числе ООП и некоторые API. Пора бы создать какой-нибудь проект чтобы закрепить свои знания, но я не знаю как это делать. Например, я могу сделать регистрацию/вход, загрузку файлов, вывод всего этого. Умею парсить XML, генерировать капчи. Но при этом сайт написать я не могу. Дело в том, что если сейчас начать писать сайт, то если и получится, то это будет плохой код. Где-то будут позорные алгоритмы, где-то будет смешной функционал, где-то будет позор полный и т.д. Не подскажите ли мне такой ресурс, видео, книгу и т.п. в котором подробно бы объяснялись именно принципы реализации сайтов, блогов, интернет-магазинов. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @tooq, вы мне напомнили анекдот про передачу "Поле чудес", где мужик отгадал все буквы, но не смог прочитать слово. )) Если, как вы говорите, "Учил много, знаю много", если вы учили не по видеокурсам Попова (*прости Господи*), то в чем тогда загвоздка? Все кирпичики ваших знаний, вам надо просто сложить вместе. И естественно, что для создания сайта, вам бы не помешало знать основы верстки (HTML, CSS). Вы не указали последнее, но возможно, что это вам не чуждо.

Comment: @Deonis, я похож на идиота?) Попова я не смотрел, а насчет html и css, то я их знаю даже очень хорошо. Вполне могу уже работать верстальщиком) Теперь насчет "кирпичиков"... В этом то и дело. Мне и нужно собрать все эти долбаные кирпичи, но я не знаю как...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сколько много нехороших слов в конце... Вопрос ваш риторический.

Дальше у вас 2 пути на мой взгляд, делать первый сайт вам однозначно придётся, особенно если вы хотите этим потом зарабатывать.

1. Набивать шишки и писать, то о чем вы говорили, потом всё это переписывать и снова писать. Результат - вы будете знать язык, в конце концов у вас будет фактический свой движок.
2. Освоить фреймворк или даже не один, они частично избавят вас от написания костылей и пользуются спросом у работодателей.

---

Если вас интересуют методы написания сайта(без фреймворка),  то основных тоже два.

Либо у вас каждая страница запускает отдельный реальный файл, в котором подключаются необходимые модули.

Либо делается редирект на обработчик, который обрабатывает запрос и автоматически подключает всё необходимое.

Конечно последний вариант предпочтительнее. Кроме того рекомендую писать страницы отдельными модулями, а не раскладывать всё по
отдельным папкам css, js, ... так будет проще переносить наработки из проекта в проект.

Comment: Верю в первый путь, так как не надо будет в дополнение к своим багам разбираться с фреймворком и гадать на кофейной гуще, как оно там всё работает. На второй путь стоит переходить, когда шишки от первого уже заживут :)

Answer (score 3):

Я тоже так думал.
Начал писать. Первый раз получилось так, что все функции были в одном файле. Тогда я знал мало чего о PHP вообще.
Дальше я почитал о ООП, создал классы, стал их автоматически подгружать. Взял алгоритмы, которые написал в предыдущей версии. Так стало получше.
Дальше узнал о шиблонизаторах, вставил Smarty. Попутно менял алгоритмы, менял БД, все менял, кардинально менял на основе нового опыта. Сейчас все вполне работает, но я продолжаю оптимизировать, дописывать функционал, сейчас, например, переписываю панель администратора.
Просто начните с чего-то примитивного, потом само пойдет!
Удачи :) .

Answer (score 1):

Вы много знаете, и думаете, что нужно что-то еще. Но больше для начала создания сайтов ничего не надо. То есть хватит теории, приступайте к практике. Я думаю, этого достаточно, чтоб начать верстать. Т.о. во время создания первого (может не первого) сайта Вы  поймете, каких знаний не хватает или что учить. А Вы хотите еще что-то. Просто найдите какой-то сайт и попробуйте сделать что-то подобное. Во первых, Вы получите опыт и результат теоретических занятий (хоть он, возможно, будет с плохим кодом). Но потом его сможете улучшать и учиться на ошибках. Я сам только учусь (самоучка) и мне очень нравится, но я начинал с:

1. идеи сайта;
2. потом смотрел, что нужно, чтобы осуществить то, что где-то увидел или то, что мне было необходимо;
3. искал примеры, литературу;
4. реализовывал;
5. пункт 2 3 4 повторять до конца.

Так намного интереснее и проще. Ну и до сих пор так делаю пункт 5.

Answer (score 0):

тебе нужно изучать паттерны проектирования приложений. знать принципы и синтаксис недостаточно.